# Class of c.d.f such that $\lim_{\infty}x(1-F(x))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Say random variable $x$ has c.d.f $F()$. I am looking for simple sufficient conditions such that the $\lim_{x\to \infty}x(1-F(x))=0$?  Bounded support is clearly sufficient.   I could not prove that finite mean (Ex finite) was sufficient (even if $x$ has positive support).

Comment: Notice that $$x(1-F(x))=x\mathbf{P}[X>x]=\mathbf{E}[x\mathbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}]. $$ So if $X_+:=\max\{X,0\}$ has finite expectation, then by the dominated convergence theorem we have $x(1-F(x))\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Nice idea.  A sufficient condition such that X_+ has finite expectation, for example, is X\geq0 and EX finite.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to assume here is to assume that there exists $a_0,\epsilon$ so that for all $x > a_0$

$$
1-F(x) < \frac{1}{x^{1+\epsilon}}
$$

But you have a good approach, use partial integration and assume $X>0,EX<\infty$, then
$$
   \int_0^a x F(dx)dx = -a(1 - F(a)) + \int_0^a(1-F(x))\,dx 
$$

But we also have the identity
$$
EX = \int_0^{\infty}(1-F(x))\,dx
$$
This beacause you calculate the same area by this as using $'xf_X'$

This then should indicate the limit.